# How to create donut pie charts using easypiechart.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, easypie

My goal is to create 6 donut pie charts using easypiechart.js like this: 
[image]
I follow every step of the instruction from [here](http://rendro.github.io/easy-pie-chart/)

I believe I link all the external resources in my JSFiddle.
I am not sure why, I still couldn't get them to display.
Can someone help me?

[`JS Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/72f1a7aa/)

Comment: First of all, classnames cannot start with number. If they do, you would need to point them with `tag[class=6]`, not `tag.6`. - Working on your Fiddle

Comment: Thanks. I fixed my class-name, and update my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you had a problem with a reference to an external resource. In your case, you should have used `jquery.easypiechart.js`, which is available on this CDN: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/easy-pie-chart/2.1.4/jquery.easypiechart.js

I included into your Fiddle, and worked [here](http://jsfiddle.net/678vr59w/1/)

I think you still have some css problems. You should re-check your external resources.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I was trying to link the raw code from: [https://github.com/rendro/easy-pie-chart](https://github.com/rendro/easy-pie-chart) in my fiddle. If you can show me, what is the proper way to do that will be great.

Comment: Another quick question, where did you get that CDN from?

Comment: In practice, you should download it from dist folder and import into your project. Remember to use the jquery version, since you want to bind it using JQuery. From here I got the CDN: http://cdnjs.com/libraries/easy-pie-chart

Comment: I think inside JSFiddle you have only the option to point to an external URI. Besides pasting the entire code from the library, of course, not very pretty.

Comment: Let's put the CDN aside, I got that now. Just wondering, have you personally link any raw code like *anything*.min.js directly from GitHub to your Fiddle?  What do you know what I mean ?

Comment: GitHub doesn't really give you the raw code when you link it. Just do a simple test and "Save Link As..." in a js file link inside github. Open the downloaded js file, and you will see a bunch of html, which actually composes the page where GitHub shows the code.

Comment: Check this out : [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rendro/easy-pie-chart/master/dist/jquery.easypiechart.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rendro/easy-pie-chart/master/dist/jquery.easypiechart.js)

Comment: Is CDN is the only way to link to Fiddle External Resource then ?

Comment: Cool. Didn't know that one. That's actually a good question. You should ask here on StackOverflow.

Comment: all right, I will ask about this later. Thanks for help.